# Convert Editable to Edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have set a tag to An Edittext variable.i want get that tag inside text TextWatcher afterTextChanged method.but there is a Editable parameter not Edittext.

here is my code.....

```
EditText filled = new EditText(DamageCount.this);
        filled.setId(100);
        filled.setTag(5);
```

and i want get that tag in

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}
```

this method

------Edited----------------
my whole java class

```
public class DamageCount extends Activity {

    private Button button_next;
    static TableLayout tl = null;
    private DbWorker dbworker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_damage_count);
        DamageCount.this
                .setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        button_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_next);
        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.show_competitor_product);
        dbworker = new DbWorker(this);
          Static_Values.arrayListdam_no = new ArrayList<DamegeItemSerialNoModel>();
        button_next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*Intent new_one = new Intent(DamageCount.this,
                        Invoice_or_prev.class);
                startActivity(new_one);
                finish();*/
                for(DamegeItemSerialNoModel dmmm :Static_Values.arrayListdam_no)
                {
                    System.out.println("Item id is "+dmmm.getItem_id()+" serial no is "+dmmm.getSerial_no());
                }




            }
        });

        Cursor cur_products= dbworker.getAllProduct();
        int i=0;
        if(cur_products.moveToFirst())
        {

            do{
                i++;
            //  Static_Values.item.put(, value)
                add_tbl_row(i,cur_products.getString(3),cur_products.getString(1));

            }
            while(cur_products.moveToNext());
        }
            else {

            }

        cur_products.close();


    }

    public void add_tbl_row(int value, String name, String tag) {

        Static_Values.damaged_id=tag;
        TableRow new_row = new TableRow(DamageCount.this);
System.out.println(Static_Values.damaged_id+" id bbb");
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        new_row.addView(imageView);

        TextView size = new TextView(DamageCount.this);
        size.setId(1);
        size.setText(name);

        size.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        new_row.addView(size);

        EditText filled = new EditText(DamageCount.this);
        filled.setId(100 * value);
        filled.setTag(tag);
        filled.setHint("Enter Damaged");
        filled.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        new_row.addView(filled);

        filled.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

              //  Toast.makeText(DamageCount.this, s.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(s.toString().equals("")==false)
                {

                final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(DamageCount.this);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                Button dialogButton = new Button(DamageCount.this);
                dialogButton.setText("Add");
            //  dialogButton.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.yellobutton);
                Static_Values.num_of_serials=Integer.parseInt(s.toString());

                for(int i=1;i<Integer.parseInt(s.toString())+1;i++)
                {
                     EditText serial = new EditText(DamageCount.this);
                    serial.setId(33*i);

                    serial.setHint("Enter serial");

                layout.addView(serial);
                }



                layout.addView(dialogButton);


                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(DamageCount.this);
                dialog.setContentView(layout);

                dialog.setTitle("Serial Numbers");

                dialog.getWindow().setTitleColor(Color.BLUE);



                // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button


            //  dialog.setContentView(filled);
        //      dialog.getOwnerActivity().setContentView(filled);



                // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog

                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {



                            for (int i = 1; i < Static_Values.num_of_serials+1; i++) {



                                View vv = dialog.findViewById(33*i);

                                EditText et=(EditText)vv;

                                System.out.println(et.getText().toString());

                                DamegeItemSerialNoModel  dism = new DamegeItemSerialNoModel();
                                dism.setItem_id(Static_Values.damaged_id);

                                System.out.println(Static_Values.damaged_id);

                                dism.setSerial_no(et.getText().toString());


                                 Static_Values.arrayListdam_no.add(dism);

                            }




                            Static_Values.num_of_serials = 0;
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                });

                dialog.show();




            }

            }
        });





        tl.addView(new_row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    }



}
```

Comment: why don't you use `filled.getTag()` then ?

Comment: no i cant that Edittext in a different method and i implement that textwatcher class

Comment: declare it globally and make it `public static` if your `TextWatcher` is in different class.

Comment: i think most of you guys misunderstood my question so i decided to provide my whole class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a constructor in yout Textwatcher class and pass the editext to it.

```
public class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher
{
private transient EditText editText = null;
public MyTextWatcher(EditText editText)
{
super();
this.editText = editText;
}
    @Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert `Editable` to simple text line (`String`), use this in your method:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    String str = s.toString();
}
```